# UIPanGestureRecognizer get translation for each touch point

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to a parent view, with various `CCSprite` I want to move around in the parent when panned. Using `[gesture locationOfTouch:i inView:recognizer.view]` I can get the location of the touch but if I assign that to my subview's center it often makes the subview move unexpectedly since the original touch is probably not in the exact center of the sprite. Really what I want is to get the `[gesture translationInView:recognizer.view]` for each of the touch locations and use that. It works perfect when you only have 1 panning touch, but more then 1 and there appears no way to get translations for them. Because each touch can be panning in a different directon/speed. The user can use 2 fingers to move two different sprite completely independent of each other. -[UIPanGestureRecognizer translationInView:] doesn't allow me to get the different translations.

How should I do this?

Comment: umm.. what's wrong with `-[UIPanGestureRecognizer translationInView:]` for a multi-touch gesture? why do you need separate translation for each touch? (btw you can do this if you keep track of touches and save the last location)

Comment: Because each touch can be panning in a different directon/speed. So the user can use 2 fingers to move two different subviews completely independent of each other. `-[UIPanGestureRecognizer translationInView:]` doesn't allow me to get the different translations.

Comment: then shouldn't you have 2 separate gesture recognizers, one on each subview?

Comment: While that would work normally the subviews are actually Cocos2d sprites and not truly subviews so I can't attach a gesture recognizer to them.

Comment: Ah, I see your predicament. Please add these details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a category [CCNode-SFGestureRecognizers](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/CCNode-SFGestureRecognizers) that adds the ability to attach `UIGestureRecognizers` to any `CCNode`. This way I can get around needing multiple translation values.

Answer (score 0):

Now, if you're only interested in pan gesture, why not use cocos touch methods?

In `touchBegan:` calculate (and save) the location of touch in the subview, in `touchMoved:`, calculate translation which is just current location less the previous location. Move your subview by that amount.

Comment: I have pan, rotate, and pinch all able to happen at any time.

Comment: Ok. You can add transparent views (`UIView`) on top which match the exact dimensions and position of your sprites and whatever changes you do to this transparent UIView, you apply the same on `CCSprite`. Does that make sense? It might be worth looking into [this](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/CCNode-SFGestureRecognizers)

Comment: I looked into this but performance was horrible. Thanks for the idea though. I got it working using a category that makes gesture recognizers able to attach to a `CCNode`. See my answer above.

Comment: Glad I could help! Btw, does CCNode-SFGestureRecognizers create new gesture recognizer class or is it able to utilize Apple's gesture recognizers?

Comment: You use Apple's gesture recognizers.